# I want to create a vbs script that will output the username as username.txt

Tags: vbscript

I want to create a vbs script that will output a text file with the users name when that user logs in. For example when john logs in it will create john.txt to a selected folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim oFSO, oTxtFile

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

If oFSO.FileExists("C:\Logs\" & CurrentUser() & ".txt")  Then
   Msgbox "File Exist"
   Set oTxtFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\Logs\" & CurrentUser() & ".txt",8)
Else 
   Set oTxtFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Logs\" & CurrentUser() & ".txt") 
   Msgbox "File Created"
End If

oTxtFile.WriteLine(CurrentUser() & " logged in at " & now() & Chr(13) & Chr(10))

Function CurrentUser()
   Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
   CurrentUser = objNetwork.username
End Function
```